# How to set either profile name else user name in my php code

Tags: php

I want show my message system user Profile name(If have) else show user name.

In my every code I used as below, which work well.

```
if (empty($pname)) $pname = $username;
```

But in below I cannot understand how to Return 'profile name else user name' in my "function getusername($userid)".

Here if I use return $row[0] at my "function getusername" Its show username, But I want to show Profile name and If profile name empty then show user name.

Get profile name/user name code:

```
 function getusername($userid) {
   $sql = "SELECT username,pname FROM users WHERE `id` = '".$userid."' LIMIT 1";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     $username = $row['username'];
     $pname = $row['pname'];

     if (empty($pname)) $pname = $username;
     // Now here return $row[0] show only username But How to return pname else username?

     return $row[0];
   } else {
      return "Unknown";
    }
 }
```

This code fetch a specific message

```
 function getmessage($message) {
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE `id` = '".$message."' && (`from` = '".$this->userid."' || `to` = '".$this->userid."') LIMIT 1";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
     // reset the array
     $this->messages = array();

     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
     $this->messages[0]['id'] = $row['id'];
     $this->messages[0]['title'] = $row['title'];
     $this->messages[0]['message'] = $row['message'];

     $this->messages[0]['from'] = $this->getusername($row['from']);
     $this->messages[0]['to'] = $this->getusername($row['to']);

   } else {
     return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
function getusername($userid) {
   $sql = "SELECT username,pname FROM users WHERE `id` = '".$userid."' LIMIT 1";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     $username = $row['username'];
     $pname = $row['pname'];

     if (empty($pname)) $pname = $username;
     // Now here return $row[0] show only username But How to return pname else username?

     return $pname;
   } else {
      return "Unknown";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with how you are returning the value.

Change:

```
if (empty($pname)) $pname = $username;
// Now here return $row[0] show only username But How to return pname else username?

return $row[0];
```

To:

```
if(empty($pname)) return $username;
else return $pname;
```

Also, it is suggested you use mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: Accidentally pressed enter before I finished typing.

Comment: Wasn't sure you had noticed that, didn't want to be aggressive at all! (and wasn't too ;D)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use something like this?

```
return isset($pname) ? $pname : $username;
```

This basically is: if $pname is set, then return $pname, else return $username